# $\Delta f=0$ in $\{x\in U:f(x)>0\}$ $\Rightarrow$ $\Delta f=0$ in $U$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, partial-differential-equations, harmonic-functions, laplacian

Let $f\geq0$ be a continuous function satisfying $\Delta f=0$ in $\{x\in U:f(x)>0\}$.

I was wondering if one could follow $\Delta f=0$ in $U$, especially in the cases $f\in C^2$ or $\Delta f=0$ in a weak sense.

So I've tried to show it for $\Delta u=0$ in weak sense, e.g.
$$
\int_U\nabla f\nabla\phi=0
$$for all $\phi\in C_0^\infty(U)$.
I've considered instead of just $\phi$ the function $\phi \eta_\delta(f)$ with a bounded function $\eta_\delta$ satisfying $\eta_\delta(x)=0$ if $x\leq \delta$ and $\eta_\delta(x)=1$ if $x\geq 2\delta$. Then we get for the left side
$$
\int \eta_\delta(f)\nabla f\nabla\phi+\int\eta_\delta'(f)\nabla f\nabla f
$$Now I've tried to focus on some other conditions for $\eta_\delta'$ but it didn't get me any further.

Any hints how you can show $\Delta f=0$ in $U$?

Comment: Did you leave out a hypothesis? As stated the answer is obviously no; the function could do more or less anything in the set where it's negative. For that matter, any strictly negative function satisfies your hypothesis...

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Let's take a continuous and nonnegative function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. Let $U=\Bbb R^2$, $f(x,y)=|x|$.

Comment: okay. Does the property hold for subharmonic functions?

Comment: It's trivial for non-negative subharmonic functions, just from the definition.

Comment: Instead of considering that, consider the _definition_ of subharmonic: For every p there exists $\rho>0$ such that for every $r\in(0,\rho)$, $u(p)$ is no larger than the average of $u$ over a circle with center $p$ and radius $r$. That's clear for $p$ in the set $f>0$ because $f$ is harmonic there. And it's clear if $f(p)=0$ as well...

Comment: okay, got it. But what I've meant above is the situation given $\Delta f\geq-1$ in $\{f>0\}$, it follows $\Delta f\geq -1$ in U, so even more general?

Comment: Could be, dunno.